# Javascript mutiple onClick() functions can run at once when need only 1 at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Presently, I have a few video links on my site that, when the user clicks them, the coorisponding video is displayed with a fadeIn and fadeOut animation.  If the user happens to click on say... video 1 and then clicks video 2 before the animation completes, it displays 2 videos when it should display only 1.  Does anyone now how to keep javascript from running multiple functions at once?

Code:

```
$(function(){

var animeReviewsLink = $('#anime-reviews-link');
var animeReviews = $('#anime-reviews');
var animeReviewsText = $('#anime-reviews-text');
var animeCommentsLink = $('#anime-comments-link');
var animeComments = $('#anime-comments');
var animeCommentsText = $('#anime-comments-text');
var animeImagesLink = $('#anime-images-link');
var animeImages = $('#anime-images');
var animeImagesText = $('#anime-images-text');
var animeVideosLink = $('#anime-videos-link');
var animeVideos = $('#anime-videos');
var animeVideosText = $('#anime-videos-text');

var active1 = animeReviewsLink;
var active2 = animeReviews;
var active3 = animeReviewsText;

animeReviewsLink.click(function(e)
{
    active3.hide();
    active1.show();
    animeReviewsLink.hide();
    animeReviewsText.show();
    active2.slideUp(400);
    animeReviews.slideDown(400);
    active1 = animeReviewsLink;
    active2 = animeReviews;
    active3 = animeReviewsText;
    setTimeout(function(){},500);
});

animeCommentsLink.click(function(e)
{
    active3.hide();
    active1.show();
    animeCommentsLink.hide();
    animeCommentsText.show();
    active2.slideUp(400);
    animeComments.slideDown(400);
    active1 = animeCommentsLink;
    active2 = animeComments;
    active3 = animeCommentsText;
    setTimeout(function(){},500);
});

animeImagesLink.click(function(e)
{
    active3.hide();
    active1.show();
    animeImagesLink.hide();
    animeImagesText.show();
    active2.slideUp(400);
    animeImages.slideDown(400);
    active1 = animeImagesLink;
    active2 = animeImages;
    active3 = animeImagesText;
    setTimeout(function(){},500);
});

animeVideosLink.click(function(e)
{
    active3.hide();
    active1.show();
    animeVideosLink.hide();
    animeVideosText.show();
    active2.slideUp(400);
    animeVideos.slideDown(400);
    active1 = animeVideosLink;
    active2 = animeVideos;
    active3 = animeVideosText;
    setTimeout(function(){},500);
});
});
```

I have tried using setTimeout at the end of each function but it seems that doesn't prevent it from running multiple functions at the same time.

EDIT: fiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/vcvpu22q/

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle demo? :)

Comment: Give me a couple minutes and ill put one together.

Comment: That took longer than it should have... http://jsfiddle.net/vcvpu22q/

Comment: If you click on both links quickly, it displays both divs at the same time which is not what I want.

Comment: **Edit:** Added an answer as it was too long for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this? (edited)

```
$(function(){
var button1 = $('#button1');
var button2 = $('#button2');
var button1text = $('#button1text');
var button2text = $('#button2text');
var button1click = $('#button1click');
var button2click = $('#button2click');    
var canClickButton = true;

button1.click(function(e){
    if(!canClickButton){return;}

    canClickButton = false;
    button2text.hide();
    button2.show();
    button1.hide();
    button1text.show();
    button2click.fadeOut(500,function(){button1click.fadeIn(500)});

    setTimeout(function(){canClickButton = true;}, 1000);

});

button2.click(function(e){
    if(!canClickButton){return;}

    canClickButton = false;
    button1text.hide();
    button1.show();
    button2.hide();
    button2text.show();
    button1click.fadeOut(500, function(){ button2click.fadeIn(500) } );

    setTimeout(function(){canClickButton = true; }, 1000);

});
```

});

Comment: unfortunately, it still does the same thing... if you click to quickly, you end up with pure text(all the links go and hide) and it displays alll the divs when it should only display 1.

Comment: It looks like your code is more or less attempting to do what I want it to do but for some reason its not working.

Comment: Slightly edited the code, this way the fadeIn/fadeOut looks a little better, but I don't know if this is exactly what you want to obtain

Comment: Same problem although now I have the fiddle working so it might be something to do with my site's script... give me a few to see why its breaking.

Comment: Ok, I copied my sites code into jsfiddle and it works, however, it does not work on my site itself in terms of the boolean for whatever reason.  Perhaps it is due to a difference in the loaded version of jquery.

Comment: I found the problem why it wasn't working.  I was modifying the wrong file (go figure) so that would be why nothing worked.  Your answer was still the only one that worked regardless.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use .stop() before anything else. It will stop the current animation, and do yours, instead of infinitely running them.

So in your click functions, add:

```
active3.stop().hide();
active1.stop().show();
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.preventDefault();

```
$(function(){

var animeReviewsLink = $('#anime-reviews-link');
var animeReviews = $('#anime-reviews');
var animeReviewsText = $('#anime-reviews-text');
var animeCommentsLink = $('#anime-comments-link');
var animeComments = $('#anime-comments');
var animeCommentsText = $('#anime-comments-text');
var animeImagesLink = $('#anime-images-link');
var animeImages = $('#anime-images');
var animeImagesText = $('#anime-images-text');
var animeVideosLink = $('#anime-videos-link');
var animeVideos = $('#anime-videos');
var animeVideosText = $('#anime-videos-text');

var active1 = animeReviewsLink;
var active2 = animeReviews;
var active3 = animeReviewsText;

animeReviewsLink.click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    active3.hide();
    active1.show();
    animeReviewsLink.hide();
    animeReviewsText.show();
    active2.slideUp(400);
    animeReviews.slideDown(400);
    active1 = animeReviewsLink;
    active2 = animeReviews;
    active3 = animeReviewsText;
    setTimeout(function(){},500);
});

animeCommentsLink.click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    active3.hide();
    active1.show();
    animeCommentsLink.hide();
    animeCommentsText.show();
    active2.slideUp(400);
    animeComments.slideDown(400);
    active1 = animeCommentsLink;
    active2 = animeComments;
    active3 = animeCommentsText;
    setTimeout(function(){},500);
});

animeImagesLink.click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    active3.hide();
    active1.show();
    animeImagesLink.hide();
    animeImagesText.show();
    active2.slideUp(400);
    animeImages.slideDown(400);
    active1 = animeImagesLink;
    active2 = animeImages;
    active3 = animeImagesText;
    setTimeout(function(){},500);
});

animeVideosLink.click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    active3.hide();
    active1.show();
    animeVideosLink.hide();
    animeVideosText.show();
    active2.slideUp(400);
    animeVideos.slideDown(400);
    active1 = animeVideosLink;
    active2 = animeVideos;
    active3 = animeVideosText;
    setTimeout(function(){},500);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
button1.click(function (e) {
        if (animation == 0) {
            animation = 1;
            button2text.hide();
            button2.show();
            button1.hide();
            button1text.show();
            button2click.fadeOut(400, function () {
                animation = 0;
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                button1click.fadeIn(500);
            }, 500);
        }

    });
```

[Have a look at the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o61by5mz/1/)

What I did was define a variable `animation`. Either set of code is allowed to execute if `animation` is 0. Else they do not execute. This gives them exclusive rights to execute their procedure.